# plotting dendrograms

Tags: r, plot

I want to merge two dendrograms from clustering results by `grid.arrange` function. The code I used is

```
d.a <- dist(df.a, method = "euclidean")
# Hierarchical clustering 
res.hc.a <- hclust(d.a, method = "ward.D2" )

d.b <- dist(df.b, method = "euclidean")
# Hierarchical clustering 
res.hc.b <- hclust(d.b, method = "ward.D2" )

p1=plot(res.hc.a, cex = 0.75,main="a")
rect.hclust(res.hc.a, k = 6, border = 2:7)

p2=plot(res.hc.b, cex = 0.75,main="b")
rect.hclust(res.hc.b, k = 7, border = 2:8)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, top  = "Dendrograms")
```

But I faced an error like this

```
Error in gList(list(wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

The problem is that `grid.arrange` function doesn't consider second line of each plot code. I don't know how to fix this problem. The second problem I have is that I want to show each dendrogram vertical instead of horizontal. Any idea about it?

Comment: I don't think grid.arrange can handle ordinary plots.  It can works with ggplot() and friends.

Comment: So how can I do such thing? @OttToomet

Comment: Try plotting with ```par(mfrow=c(1,2))```.  This should make 1x2 grid in the plot window.  However, I am not quite sure what will you get when plotting hclust objects.  It is possible that it invokes ggplot although ggplot-related routines typically start with gg.